# How to tell if overflow ellipses are visible on a block HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ellipsis

I have a number of block elements (`div`s) with potentially long text. The blocks have CSS

```
.el-clip {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to clip any text that extends past the end of the divs, and I want my Javascript to know whether the text in a given `div` is showing the ellipses, so I can add some mouseover text (`title` attribute) to show the full text.

Please note, I've seen [this question "Detect if text-overflow:ellipsis is active on input field"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10209831/1431728), but it's about `input` elements, not normal block elements, and the existing solutions are not optimal for my question.

My idea for a solution is to compare the width of the element to the width of the same element with an inline style `overflow: visible` added. If the former is less than the latter, then the ellipses are in use. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution, or (perhaps even) a built-in solution.

UPDATE
Wow, I'm surprised. While adding inline style `overflow: visible` shows the full element, the width remains the same. So my proposed solution doesn't work.

Apparently the width is still constrained by the parent element? That is totally weird. I should note that the div with the text is inside an `li` and there's a `maxWidth` on the `ul`. Is it even possible to make a general purpose function that does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution. I discovered `scrollWidth` gives the full width including any overflow, so I don't even have to fiddle around with the styles of the element. This works for jQuery:

```
addTooltipToLongText = function($el) {
  if (!($el instanceof $)) {
    $el = $($el);
  }
  $el.each( (i, it) => {
    const $it = $(it);
    if ($it.width() < it.scrollWidth) {
      $it.prop('title', $it.text());
    }
  });
}
```