# Does html textarea support cyclic display of text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

What I am trying to get is a text field of a fixed size (with a height of exactly one row) where you can type some text. If the text is short enough to fit in the text field it should just be displayed. But if the text is too long it should be displayed in a cycle, e.g. it constantly moves across the field and starts over. Like a continues sideways scroll of an infinite cyclic string, like you may have seen on news television. This should happen immediately after the user stops typing.

My question:
Is it possible to achieve this with just using html-textarea/css/js?
Maybe there is a way to smoothly scroll sideways through the typed text and seemlessly jump back to the beginning?
I can create a html textarea with all of properties that I need (like hidden scrollbar, fixed size, only horizontal scrolling) but I do not know how to make the text move in the above described way.

I am not limited to using the bulit-in textarea from html so if you have any other implementation ideas that can be done in html/css/js - they are welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you define when the user stops typing, and what happens if they almost immediately start typing again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't something native for that. This is a hacky solution. First detecting the overflow, but [it's possible to hack it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209831/detect-if-text-overflowellipsis-is-active-on-input-field). For simplicity I'll assume length of string. Then when it "overflows" I shall rotate the string. It's important to reset when keydown again.

All in all, Maybe a more robust solution would be to rotate on `blur` and stop on `focus`.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var int_id;

function debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

function is_overflow(input) {
  // for now:
  return input.value.length >= 14
}


input.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  stop(input)
})

function stop(input) {
  if (int_id) {
    clearInterval(int_id)
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-value") || input.value
    int_id = null;
  }
}
input.addEventListener('input', debounce(function(ev) {
  if (is_overflow(input)) {
    input.setAttribute("data-value", input.value);
    int_id = setInterval(function() {
      rotate(input)
    }, 100);
  } else {
    stop(input)
  }
}))

function rotate(input) {
  var str = input.value
  var num = 1;
  input.value = str.substr(num) + str.substr(0, num);


}
```

```html
<input style="width:100px">
```

Comment: Great! This is pretty much what I have been looking for. The cyclic animation is a bit jittery but I would assume that this is about as good as it gets when only using textarea. Thank you very much!